# boolean flag in javascript is not checking properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've created a sample application which checks when i press a key or mouse, but the problem is when mouse or when key is pressed it prints the console **"Enter is pressed"** and **"Enter is not pressed some Mouse event is clicked"**, that boolean checking is not working properly i think so,

can anyone please tell me some solution

```
$('#adminPanel').bind("searchMaster", function(event, data)
{
    var press = true;
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
       var  code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
       if (code == 13) 
       {
         console.log("Enter is pressed");
         press = false;
       }
    });

    if(press)
    {
        console.log("Enter is not pressed, some Mouse event is clicked");   
        // some other action to be triggered if key is not pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your `searchMaster` event?

Comment: actually we are using one project based plugin and `searchMaster` event is a part of it

Comment: Does it fire when you have a mouse click? And should the mouse click be handled only if enter is not pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, (a) that you register the keypress event inside the click callback and (b) that you set `press` to `false`, if is pressed and (c) that you never reset the value of `press` every time you click with the mouse.

I suggest you split the two callbacks up and move `press` outside of the callbacks. In the example `press` => `enterPressed`. The `enterPressed` and the callbacks are wrapped in an IIFE to not poluted the global namespace.

```
 (function () {
    // by default, "enter" is not pressed
    var enterPressed = false;

    // Suppose this event is triggered by mouse clicks
    $("#adminPanel").bind("searchMaster", function (event, data) {
        if (!enterPressed) {
            // Handle Mouse Click (no "enter" pressed here)
        }
    });

    // This callback will be triggered if you press a key
    // and if you release a key
    $("#adminPanel").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        // check if the pressed/released key was "enter"
        if (code === 13) {
            enterPressed = !enterPressed;
        }
    });
})();
```